# Create a Details Form from a GridView c#

Tags: c#, runtime, controls, detailsview

Possibly a complex question - but here's hoping

I have a generic data grid on a single form (displays whatever table I want from a dataset) simply by swapping tables in the dataset.

I want to double-click on a given record and display a single-record view of the table data with the currently selected record displayed as default, but with the option to page through and edit/view/delete other records  i.e.

I want to automatically create a details view form from a datagrid for a given table at runtime.  The form should be dynamically created - displaying the dataset in details view with the option to page through single records using the binding source/binding source navigator.

My goal is to improve efficiency/maintainability of the application - rather than create and manage 10+ forms, I simply want to create and manage I generic details form in the same way as I manage I generic gridview form.

**So  far I have come up with:**

public void CreateDetailsForm(BindingSource bs, int rowClicked)
 {
            Form detailsForm = new Form();

```
        BindingSource newFormBS = new BindingSource();

        //assign binding source for use on new detailsForm
        newFormBS = bs;

        //assign binding source to datatable
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;

        //create the form fields
        CreateFormFields(dt);  //not yet implemented

        //assign form fields to form

       //display form
```

}

Any help on the following appreciated

1. Generating and assigning the form fields to the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it likes:

```
Form f=new Form();

        TextBox t=new TextBox();//generate the controls u need
        t.Text = "test";//set the actual value
        t.Location=new Point(10,10);
        f.Controls.Add(t);

        DialogResult dr=f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks - have used this code to generate the form with text boxes and labels - now all I need to do is work out how to bind the controls on the form to the binding source.

Comment: You are welcome,i think u can generate a datagridview or something list control to display your datasource

Answer (score 0):

So far I have got the col names generated on the form as follows

List colNames = GetColumnNames(dt);

```
        int offset=25;
        int xPos=50;
        int yPos = 10;
        foreach (string name in colNames)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Name = name;
            l.Width = 200;
            l.Text = name;


            TextBox t = new TextBox();
            t.Name = name; 
            t.Width=200;

            l.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos );
            t.Location = new Point(xPos+250, yPos);


           f.Controls.Add(l);
           f.Controls.Add(t);

           yPos = yPos + offset;
        }
        //TextBox t = new TextBox();//generate the controls u need
        //t.Text = "test";//set the actual value


        f.Width = 800;
        f.Height = 600;
        f.Show();


    }

    private List<string> GetColumnNames(DataTable table)
    {
        List<string> lstColNames=new List<string>();

        if (table != null)
        {

             lstColNames=

                (from DataColumn col in table.Columns

                 select col.ColumnName).ToList();



        }

        return lstColNames;



    }
```

Now trying to work on getting the controls to bind to the binding source!

Comment: Have now worked out the binding operation for a single record - but working on whole table being available                                                                                                                               //binding operation
                t.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, t.Name, true));

Answer (score 0):

OK - got it working now - had to take a different approach

1. Created a single detailsView Form
2. Created a static class called PassBindingSource with a static property bst for passing binding source from gridview to details form

   static class PassBindingSource
   {
      public static BindingSource bst { get; set; }
   }
3. On the detailsView form added the following code

   ```
   try{  bs.DataSource = PassBindingSource.bst;

   DataTable dt = (DataTable)PassBindingSource.bst.DataSource;


   List<string> colNames = GetColumnNames(dt);

   int offset = 25;
   int xPos = 50;
   int yPos = 50;

   foreach (string name in colNames)
    {
   Label l = new Label();
    l.Name = name;
   l.Width = 200;
   l.Text = name;


   TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.Name = name;
   t.Width = 200;

    // BindingOperations.SetBinding(t, t.TextProperty, bs);

   //binding operation
   t.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, t.Name, true));

   l.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
   t.Location = new Point(xPos + 250, yPos);


   this.Controls.Add(l);
   this.Controls.Add(t);

   yPos = yPos + offset;

   // dgDetailsView.DataSource = bs;
    }
   //move to correct record in binding source
           bs.Position = PassBindingSource.currentRecord;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }



   }



   private List<string> GetColumnNames(DataTable table)
   {
   List<string> lstColNames=new List<string>();

   if (table != null)
   {

         lstColNames=

         (from DataColumn col in table.Columns

          select col.ColumnName).ToList();


   }

   return lstColNames;



   }
   ```

**SUMMARY**
Now it all works - the detailsView controls generated at run-time wired up correctly to the binding source and the datagrid can call this detailsView any time using any table from the dataset by wiring the double-click event of the gridview with the following code

```
PassBindingSource.bst= bs;
frmDetailsView nf = new frmDetailsView();
nf.Show();
```

Hope this helps others.  Many thanks to User2354374 for the initial steer.